# Copy as Input Text via Function

Tags: export, character-encoding, copy-as

I've got some code which generates a series with coefficients that are a rather complicated expressions of Greek letters with subscripts. I want to store some of these coefficients for future use, rather than computing them each time I run my program.

What I would like, is to store each coefficient as if I had used the "Copy As" -> "Input Text" functionality which you get when right clicking on a specific cell. And I would like to do this via the Export[] function rather than doing it for each coefficient manually. Does anyone know how to do this so that, in particular, the Greek letters are exported as $\backslash[\text{Rho}]$ as opposed to $\rho$. "Copy As" -> "Input Text" does this, but Export[] gives the formatted $\rho$, which causes problems on import.

Comment: Have a look at `CopyToClipboard` I think it does what you want. You should note that there are functions for saving expressions for furture usesuch as `Put` and `Save`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! `PutAppend` and then `ReadList` gives me exactly what I want.

Comment: @BillyPilgrim If you use Put and Read together, then you shouldn't write to a file.  Just use ToString.  Your question seems to ask about exporting to a file, maybe copying to the clipboard, but your comment made me suspect that you just want a string. ...

Comment: @Szabolcs What I meant by my comment is that I use `Put`/`PutAppend` to write to file, and then some time later, when I want the contents of the the file, I use `ReadList`. This provides (as far as I can tell) an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: @BillyPilgrim So your real question is how to save Mathematica expressions for later, and not how to format them in a certain way?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) with ["Package"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Package.html).  `Export["file.txt",expr,"Package", "Comments" -> None]`

Alternatively use

```
ToString[expr, InputForm]
```

then write the resulting string to a file. References: [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html), [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html)